# How does the passive form work here?

Tags: meaning, passive-voice

This is from a visual novel.

A dude is talking to his underlings:

> さって本日よりきさまらに新たな命令が下されるわけだが

It translates to

> "Well now I’m calling you to give new orders"

I was under the impression that the passive form works like this:

> A が/は B に passive form

Which means: A is affected by B’s action (directly or indirectly depending whether it's a transitive or intransitive verb)

However I don’t see how that works here.
From what I can tell the sentence is constructed like this:

> A が/は B に passive form

So the speaker should be the one being adversely affected by the verb (orders) however in this case he is the one doing the action (verb).

A should be affected by B's action. However A is the one doing the action towards B.

Can someone help?

Comment: (book title) > チャクラ開放の秘宝―あなたにも神の力が与えられる < ____________ あなたに神の力が与えられる_____________きさまらに新たな命令 が下される__________i think there's an exact parallel here.

Comment: i just had a thought about the poss. source of confusion.  There are 2 ways of making a passive sentence.  1.  You shall be given this gift (from/by me).  2. This gift shall be given to you (from/by me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> きさまら**に**新たな命令**が**下される
>   (= 新たな命令がきさまらに下される)

The に here doesn't mark the agent (subject), but the target (indirect object) of 下す. きさまらに here means "to you", not "by you".

> 「上層部が**貴様らに**新たな命令**を**下す」 -- active voice
>   (They) give new orders **to you**.
>   ↓
>   「新たな命令**が**(上層部によって/から*)**貴様らに**下される」 -- passive voice
>   New orders are given **to you** (by them).

*によって or から is preferred, avoiding repeating に, since 「上層部**に**貴様ら**に**」 would sound confusing.

下す (give) takes two objects, a direct object (marked by を) and an indirect object (marked by に), so the sentence can be converted to another passive voice form:

> 「貴様ら**が**(上層部に/から/によって)新たな命令**を**下される」
>   You are given new orders (by them).

---

Another example:

> 「私が**あなたに**１万円を渡す」 I give **you** 10,000 yen.
>   ↓
>   「１万円が(私によって/から)**あなたに**渡される」 10,000 yen is given **to you** (by me).
>   「あなたが(私に/によって/から)１万円を渡される」 You are given 10,000 yen (by me).

... So, 「山田さん**に**渡された１万円」 would be quite ambiguous: "10,000 yen that was given **to** Yamada, or **by** Yamada." (In the case of "by~~", you can usually avoid confusion by using から instead.)

---

So, logically speaking, 「～に下される」「～に与えられる」「～に渡される」「～に教えられる」「～に託される」「～に依頼される」 etc. can mean either "be given/taught/entrusted **to** ~~" or "be given/taught/entrusted **by** ~~", and you should see the context to tell which meaning a に is being used for.

Comment: 「上層部」を英語でなんて言うかわかりません・・

Comment: 上層部  & 英語 でググると --> 
Upper echelon, 
senior management ,  above brass (?)  high place  (?) the highest functionaries

Comment: ^ ありがとうございます・・そですねーでもどれが適切か、私の英語力では判断できないww

Comment: 「～に使用される/使われる/用いられる」 -> "used by someone" と "used on/as something" ってのもありますね・・・他にもいろいろあるかもしれません