# Can a passive verb modify a noun?

Tags: grammar

We can say something like this, using a passive verb at the end of a sentence:

> 英語は世界中で話されている

But when we put verb before a noun to modify it, which of the following could you use, or would be correct?

> 子供に与えられる玩具

or

> 子供に与える玩具

Answer (score 2):

You can safely put a passive verb before a noun to form a relative clause. 世界中で話されている英語 means "English which is spoken all over the world".

But please note that 子供に与えられる玩具 is ambiguous; technically it means both "the toy given **by** the child" and "the toy given **to** the child" depending on the context (although in this case the latter is more likely for obvious reasons). See: [The meaning of ”あれは魔術師に与えられた祝福”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76392/5010) and [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38744/5010). On the other hand, 子供に与える玩具 only means "the toy someone gives to a child".

Ambiguous relative clause happens with non-passive relative clauses, too. See: [Ambiguity when describing with verbs, e.g. 酒を飲ませる人](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/79905/5010) and [ambiguous-relative-clauses](/questions/tagged/ambiguous-relative-clauses).

Comment: Re: ambiguity, I think that only happens with either passive or causative (or the combined causative-passive), due to the semantics and grammar of these constructions and the multiple possible ways of interpreting agency in these contexts.  Are there any similarly ambiguous constructions with plain (non-passive, non-causative) verbs?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi How about [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30172/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60896/5010)?

Comment: Interesting, yes.  The first link is about 好き rather than a verb, but that and the 惚れる discussed in the second link both share a similar ambiguity about agency / application when used in relative clauses.  From those examples, I recognize that various other "passive-light" and "ability" verbs likely fall into this same area -- things like 分かる and 出来る, potential/realis/stative verbs like 惚れる or 切れる.  Thank you!